# Error accessing array element returned by function

Tags: php, syntax-error

Shouldn't this work?

```
$tmp = explode('=', 'name=value');
$value1 = $tmp[1]; // ok
$value2 = explode('=', 'name=value')[1]; // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

(Adding unnecessary text so that the post meet the quality standard)

Comment: the question's title needs to be improved in regards to the actual issue.

Comment: what is the version of php that this is running off of?

Comment: "(Adding unnecessary text so that the post meet the quality standard)" :D

Comment: @Xatenev just when you think you've seen it all

Comment: When even the SO robot tells you the post is poor quality...?!

Answer (score 2):

You're using <=PHP5.3 on your server and the code there is valid for PHP5.4+

Change to:

```
$value2 = explode('=', 'name=value');
$value2 = $value2[1];
```

and it will work.